# Send weekly report with cron job in linux server

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I am working with an application where I need to send weekly reports automatically to the administrator, All the application files are hosted in linux server and recently I set a `cron job` to send the weekly reports, I just want to know is there any other better way apart from cron job, which will send automatic reports?

Comment: `Cron Job` is the best, I always use it and i believe that ..!

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Anacron](http://anacron.sourceforge.net/), [fcron](http://fcron.free.fr/), [Hcron](https://expl.info/display/HCRON/Home) or [Jobber](https://github.com/dshearer/jobber).

For more details on these schedulers refer [Cron Alternatives for Linux](http://www.maketecheasier.com/cron-alternatives-linux/)